# select mobileNO which not related in other Services in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select mobile number who exist in abc service but not relate in other service

**Sample Data**

```
MobileNO    service
111111        abc
111111        def
111111        ghi
111111        jkm
222222        abc
222222        def
333333        ghi
333333        jkm
```

**Expected Outpput**

```
example 
222222    mobile number  exist in sigle service so i found this
```

Comment: Your example makes no sense. 22222 exists as abc and def

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only return rows that has no other service:

```
select * from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.MobileNO = t2.MobileNO
                    and t2.service <> 'abc')
```